# Adding a grid background image on a page in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm pretty newbie to programming but I'm trying to write an application in WPF and I hope that someone can help me out with this problem I've encountered:
I wanted to add an image in the background of a page so I looked up on microsoft tutorial how to do that, though it's not explained very well.. So I tried to follow the suggestions on other forums and co but none of them worked. 
Getting into details, I created a folder "Resources" in the project and then I put my imageR.bmp in there. After that I included the image into my project and set it as Resource in the "Build action" property.
In the page xaml, where I have to add the background, I put this code:

```html
<Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/imageR.bmp" />
</Grid.Background>
```

In the design window I can see the image on the background but when I run the application in debug mode it throws an exception that states that it couldn't find the image.

A suggestion I found is to create a Resource Dictionary and then reference to that, but I couldn't find an example about how to reference to it from the page xaml code.. The dictionary I created looks like this:

```html
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">


    <BitmapImage x:Key="imageR" UriSource="Resources/imageR.bmp"></BitmapImage>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

So, could someone tell me what am I doing wrong or suggest me a way to use the dictionary in the page xaml? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: in the first snippet, try /Resources/imageR.bmp for the ImageSource, the first / matters

Comment: no prob, i added as answer, please mark it as correct answer

Comment: ok, how do I do that? this is my first message on stackoverflow :)

Comment: all right, found it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the "/" before Resources...

```
<Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Resources/imageR.bmp" />
</Grid.Background>
```